# Redirect client to no SSL as MITM

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle, sslstrip

I'm pen testing a setup where I have an AP that I control (using wifipumkin3) and DNS spoofing to redirect the known endpoint for a firmware update. When the device requests for an update, I'm redirecting the request to an opened port that I control.

The problem is that I see the device is initiating a TLS handshake (Client hello) right after establishing a TCP connection. In my network logs, I can see the request here - [image]

I'd imagine I need to redirect the requesting client to no SSL. How can I achieve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

You can't, unless the service doesn't do certificate validation. To redirect, you'd have to send it a HTTP redirect, which you can't because it won't accept, as you probably can't present a certificate signed by a CA the device trusts.

Comment: And if you can get your cert accepted, you don't _need_ to redirect in the first place. Plus even if you can send a redirect, on a program client unlike a browser it may not work; for examples, `curl` by default doesn't follow any redirect, and Java `HttpsURLConnection` follows only within https not to http, and not at all if you change a setting.